# Minimizing the number of slopes when given $x_1$ and $x_2$ number of points

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, euclidean-geometry

Let's say that we have the total of $x_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ points lying on the negative side of the $x$-axis (let us call this set $S_1$) and $x_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ points lying on the positive side of the $y$-axis (let us call this set $S_2$). We want to determine the minimum number of slopes these points create by connecting a each point from $S_1$ to each point in $S_2$. By 'minimizing the number of slopes' I am referring to an optimal way of placing the points in $S_1$ and $S_2$ so that the number of slopes determined in the described way is as small as possible.

My idea was the following: the points on both, the $x$-axis (set $S_1$) and the $y$-axis (set $S_2$) would have to be evenly spaced from one another. This makes sense to me, I am just not entirely sure how to prove it. Going by contradiction seems that it could potentially work, but this is where I got stuck. I know that trivially the upper bound for the slopes would have to be $x_1 \cdot x_2$. The lower bound is much more difficult to think of. Would the crossings of the slopes have to be minimized as well when wanting to minimize the number of slopes?

Also, I noticed that when we want to minimize the slopes, we would have to maximize the number of slopes that appear multiple times. Such examples would be $2$, $\frac{4}{2}$, $\frac{8}{4}$ and so on. We can call these 'duplicates'.

Comment: What do you mean by "the number of slopes"? Do you mean the number of different slopes of lines connecting the points on different sides of the $y$ axis? Also, what are you allowed to change? The question so far is very unclear, please edit it to make the following points clear:

 1. What exactly you are minimizing
 2. What parameters you are allowed to change
 3. what the input to your problem is - i.e., which parameters are fixed.

Comment: I changed it now. My point of 'minimizing' means the way of placing the points on the negative $x$ and positive $y$ axis so that the number of slopes is as few as possible. There is nothing that is fixed, except the fact that we know that there is $x_1$ points on the negative $x$-axis and $x_2$ points on the positive $y$-axis.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that the points on each semi-axis must be distinct.

**Statement:** There are at least $x_1+x_2-1$ distinct slopes.

**Proof**, by descent on $x_1$:

Consider removing the left-most point of the $x_1$ points on the negative x-axis. It has $x_2$ lines connecting it to the $x_2$ points on the positive y-axis. The line connecting it to the lowest point on the y-axis has a slope that is unique, i.e. none of the other lines can have that same slope because the two sets of points lie on different sides of that line. Therefore, when you remove the left-most point and the lines through it, the number of unique slopes decreases by at least $1$.

If you repeat the above $x_1-1$ times, you get down to the case with $x_1=1$ which has $x_2$ lines that must all have unique slopes since the y-axis points are distinct.

Therefore the starting arrangement must have had at least $x_2+(x_1-1)$ unique slopes to begin with.

**Statement:** The lower bound of $x_1+x_2-1$ distinct slopes is achievable.

**Proof:** Consider the arrangement of points given by the coordinates $(-2^1,0)...(-2^{x_1},0)$ and $(0,2^1)...(0,2^{x_2})$. The slopes are all powers of two, ranging from $2^{-x_1+1}$ to $2^{x_2-1}$, and these form exactly $x_1+x_2-1$ distinct values.